# Why hex encoded characters greater than x7F displays different in printf function?

Tags: c, hex, printf

I expected the code below show two equal lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //printf("%x %x %x\n", '\x7F', (unsigned char)'\x8A', (unsigned char)'\x8B');
    printf("%x %x %x\n", '\x7F', '\x8A', '\x8B');
    printf("%x %x %x\n", 0x7F, 0x8A, 0x8B);
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
7f ffffff8a ffffff8b
7f 8a 8b
```

I  know that is maybe a overflow case. But why the **`ffffff`**`8a` (4 bytes)...?

Comment: `'%x'` conversion specifier expects an `unsigned`. You pass `int` from `char` which has implementation defined signed-ness -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: The char type on your compiler is signed.  That's very common.  And your processor uses 2's complement to represent signed values.  That's very common.

Comment: @davmac: note that `'\x7F'` has the type `int`, not `char` (and so does every other character literal).  And the arguments after the format string in `printf()` are subject to 'usual promotions', so the `char` value is passed as an `int` (and so would `unsigned char` unless `sizeof(char) == `sizeof(int)`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I see, you are correct in both cases; `%c` requires an `int` value, not actually `unsigned char`. I should have remembered this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\x8A'` is, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant),

> a single-byte integer character constant, e.g. `'a'` or `'\n'` or `'\13'`.

What is particularly interesting is the following.

> Such constant has type `int` and a value equal to the representation of *c-char* in the execution character set as a value of type `char` mapped to `int`.

This means that the conversion of `'\x8A'` to an unsigned int is implementation-defined, because `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on the system. If `char` is signed, as it seems to be the case for you (and is very common), then the value of `'\x8A'` (which is negative) as a 32-bit `int` is `0xFFFFFF8A` (also negative). However, if `char` is unsigned, then it becomes `0x0000008A` (which is why the commented line in your code works as you'd think it should).

The printf format specifier `%x` is used to [convert an unsigned integer into hexadecimal representation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Although `printf` expects an `unsigned int` and you give it an `int`, and even though the standard says that passing an incorrect type to `printf` is (generally) undefined behavior, it isn't in your case. This is because the conversion from `int` to `unsigned int` is well-defined, even though the opposite isn't.

Comment: @davmac That's what I meant. I clarified.

Comment: Unfortunately my earlier comment was incorrect, because character literals have `int` type, and a `char` (or `unsigned char`) argument is in fact promoted to an `int` before being processed; `%c` actually converts an `int` rather than a `char`, but that's ok in this case. I think your initial statement may actually have been correct.

Comment: @davmac Well, the argument for undefined behavior is still correct : the wrong type is being passed. However, I thought the value was negative because `'\x8A'` in a `signed char` is negative, but that doesn't seem to make sense knowing that the type of `'\x8A'` is `int`. Interestingly, in C++, the type of single-byte character literals is `char`, which is what I knew.

Comment: Actually, there is no undefined behavior, since the conversion from `int` to `unsigned int` is well-defined. I wonder if the standard says something about that. After all, it does say "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: the conversion is well defined, the question is whether the conversion will be applied here. I'm not so sure. 6.3.1.1 says that the result of integer promotion can be an `int` or an `unsigned int` (it would be `int` in this case). 7.21.6 (C11) says "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined". I think that then applies; `%x` requires an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @davmac Well in that case, something like `printf("%x", 0x8A)` (also in the question) would be ill-formed as well, and I think that kind of code is used quite often. Or could it be that `0x8A` is an `unsigned int` ? Even then, I'm sure there are many instances where an `int` variable is used instead of an integer constant.

Comment: "Or could it be that 0x8A is an `unsigned int`?" No, 6.4.4.4: "An integer character constant has type int". "... would be ill-formed as well, and I think that kind of code is used quite often" yes, it may be used often and it most likely works as intended in the majority of cases; that doesn't mean it's not ill-formed, though.